# Onclick event update localhost database

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, database, onclick

I have a form with a table which has 5 rows and 8 columns. This table represents the available seats in a concert hall. After the submit button is clicked, a javascript function is called, which at the moment is this:

```
    <script>
    function submit_tickets(form){
      var count=0;
      var booked_seats=new Array();
      var c = document.getElementById(form).getElementsByTagName('input');
      for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        if (c[i].type == 'checkbox' && c[i].checked==true){
        booked_seats[count]=c[i].id;
        count++;
    //create an array with the booked seats' ID
    }
    }


//alert(booked_seats.length);
    } </script>
```

When this function is called, I want at the same time the table of the localhost database to be updated (a table which contains all the 40 seatIDs) depending on the seats that were booked.
How can I do this, can you help me?

Comment: you need an ajax call that calls php script which updates the database: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I agree, ajax is what you are looking for. [Here is a good little tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajax-mysql-database.php).

Answer (score 0):

if you'd like to i can write example in native javascript, but for now i'll try to do it using jQUery.

```
function submit_tickets(form){
    var seats=[];
    $(form).find("input:checked").each(function(){
        seats.push($(this).val());//i hope you do have a value for your input tags, and if not, then push $(this).attr('id') - but highly recommend you to follow w3c   

    });
    $.post("your/url/to/server",{seats:seats},function(data){
          console.log(data);//some info from server
    })
}
```

Comment: I'd appreciate if you wrote the example in javascript. The checkboxes are like this: <td width="20" bgcolor="#FF9966"><input type="checkbox" name="Y1" id="Y1" /></td>. I figure that the database update has to be in a seperate php file which I have to call somewhere, but I don't know exactly what to write.

Comment: to write it in native js - it's not a good idea, because of fact, that you'd like to update it in server too and implement ajax it's not smart idea, people already did it. for ajax - use jQuery. 
on server side, i don't know how you implemented it there, i hope you use mvc.. - so create new method in controller.
if not, so just send it to your index file, and see what $_POST variable will include )) and you will understand what to do..
by the way i'd recommend you to add value="Y1" to your checkbox

Comment: and it's really bad, that you using bgcolor fot TD element.. much better to put class on it, or inherit from table.. imagine, that you need to update a color, instead of to change it just in 1 place in css, you have to do it a zillion times in all html files. on the other hand it's just looks not fun.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to call a php file using PHP, in which the database update is done. You might consider using jquery ajax, as in http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Suppose I figure out how to write the php file, the call command should be inside the javascript function submit_tickets() or someplace else?